# When a map is can be iterated?

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

In the paper "The Asymptotic Behavior of Firmly Nonexpansive Mappings" by Simeon Reich and Itai Shafrir the Theorem 1 claims the following:

---

> **Theorem1**  Let $D$ be a subset of a Banach space $X$ and $T: D \rightarrow X$ a *firmly nonexpansive mapping*. If $T$ **can be iterated** at $x\in D$, then for all $k\geq 1$,
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|T^{n+1}x-T^nx|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|T^{n+1}x-T^nx|/k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|T^nx/n|$$

What does it mean in this case the condition that "If $T$ can be iterated"?

Comment: It simply means that we can apply the $T$-operator arbitary often to create an arbitary long sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $T$ is $D$. To be able to apply $T$ on $T(x)$ for some $x\in D$ you need $T(x)\in D$. Therefore $T$ can be iterated at $x$ if and only if $T^kx\in D$ for all $k>0$.

If you have a self-mapping $T:D\to D$, then $T$ can be iterated at each $x\in D$.

**Example:**

Let us consider $f:(-1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$.
 The map $f$ is not a self-mapping since $f(-1,\infty)=\mathbb R$.

We see that $f$ can be iterated for all $x\geq 0$ since $f[0,\infty)=[0,\infty)$.

But for $x\in(-1,0)$ you can show that there exists $k>0$ such that $f^k(x)<-1$, hence $f$ can't be iterated at $x\in(-1,0)$.

Comment: Therefore, if I consider a self-mapping $T:D\rightarrow D$ that particular condition is always verified. Right?

Comment: Yes. A self-mapping can always be iterated.

Comment: The specific context is that $T$ can be iterated **at** $x$, so there should be some mention of this detail.  Presumably it is not generally true that $T(D) \subseteq D$ but it is still possible that $T^k(x) \in D$ for all $k>0$, for specific values of $x$.

Comment: You are right. I rewrote my answer.